# I have to write a code for pattern recognition and replacing the pattern?

Tags: python-3.x

I have this problem statement where I have a column of patterns that were if the first four bytes have date it should replace those four bytes to ccyy and the rest to N and zeros to Z's
eg. `20190045689` -> `CCYYZZNNNNN`
if space we need to consider the space as well.
`66-7830956` -> `NN-NNNZNNN`

```py
def patternGeneration(string):
    x = re.findall("[\s0-9a-zA-Z]", string)
    n = len(x)
    j = 0
    r = re.compile("\A[^(19|20)]")
    y = list(filter(r.match, x))
    b = len(y)
    for i in range(0, b):
        if y[i] == "0":
            y[i] = 0
        elif y[i] == " ":
            y[i] = " "
        else:
            y[i] = "n"
    print(convert(y))

    for i in range(0, n):
        if x[i] == "0":
            x[i] = 0
            j = j + 1
        elif x[i] == " ":
            x[i] = " "
            j = j + 1
        else:
            x[i] = "n"
    print(convert(x))


str1 = input("enter the string\t")
patternGeneration(str1)
```

Comment: Sorry but what exactöy is your question? Please also provide some sample input and the expected output.

Comment: Hi it is that if i give my input as say 20196705540 then the output should be "CCYYNN0NNN0' as 2019 is an year, and rest of the following numbers as N. Here i have tried using a regex for date as "\A[^(19|20)]"  to validate for the first two byres of the string input, but then it doesnt work.

Comment: Please do ask any further questions, thanks for the response

Comment: can the year only be at the beginning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#convert to new format
def convert(string):
    # check for year
    head = string[:4]
    tail = string[4:]
    if head.isnumeric():
        if 1900 <= int(head) <= 2099:
            head = "CCYY"
    new_string = head + tail

    return "".join(["Z" if x == "0" else "N" if x.isnumeric() else x for x in str(new_string)])

sample = "20196705540"
print(convert(sample))
#"CCYYNNZNNNZ"

sample = "66-7830956"
print(convert(sample))
#"NN-NNNZNNN"
```

Comment: If you have questions, let me know

Comment: Glad I could help, happy coding!